# How to Keep LaTeX Process Files in Directories?

Tags: paths

I want to organise better LaTeX process files such as .aux, .log, .nav, .snm, .synctex.gz, .toc and .out.
I know the threads

- [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14762/13173) about *How to manage LaTeX files in a directory?* but it is about version control management.
- [here](http://Directory%20organization%20with%20multiple%20papers%20that%20share%20files) about *Directory organization with multiple papers that share files* but it is about working with papers sharing same bibliography.

### Keep auxiliary away from your way

It is nice to keep pictures with `graphicspath` in *Images* folder such that they do not mess up the workflow. 
I would similarly like to keep the LaTeX process files in corresponding folders because I have many presentations and these process files are on my way, for instance

```
7.4.2016_presentation.aux
7.4.2016_presentation.log
7.4.2016_presentation.nav
7.4.2016_presentation.pdf
7.4.2016_presentation.snm
7.4.2016_presentation.synctex.gz
7.4.2016_presentation.toc
7.4.2016_presentation.out
7.4.2016_presentation.tex
```

Pseudocode to keep all auxiliary files in one directory

```
\auxpath{{/Users/masi/BitTorrentSync/Inf/.auxiary}}
\logpath{{/Users/masi/BitTorrentSync/Inf/.auxiary}}
\navpath{{/Users/masi/BitTorrentSync/Inf/.auxiary}}
\snmpath{{/Users/masi/BitTorrentSync/Inf/.auxiary}}
\synctexgzpath{{/Users/masi/BitTorrentSync/Inf/.auxiary}}
\tocpath{{/Users/masi/BitTorrentSync/Inf/.auxiary}}
\outpath{{/Users/masi/BitTorrentSync/Inf/.auxiary}}
```

### Removal approach

Benchmark

```
latexmk -c
```

which removes auxiliary files. 
To bind this to any editor is still unknown. 
I am using TextMate. 
I do not like the delete approach because I think those auxiliary files should be stored. Better solution would be to keep them in some directory that could be controlled by LaTeX.

---

How to Keep LaTeX LaTeX Process Files in Directories?

Comment: with tools like `ltx2any` you can keep your project folder clean

Comment: @samcarter Please, add an example as an answer about it. I think it is this one https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any

Comment: Done. ___________

Comment: I hate to see that something n the compilation went wrong and i have to go to a folder to hve a look at the detailed log. Or to see that a file isn't even generated. Or to delete a file beause of an error i made. That is why i keep everything in one dir only.

Comment: @Johannes_B How do you search documents inside your file-tree? It would be nice to understand some of your work-flow. Using any GUI of all files in directory is sometimes hopeless, without preliminary search/filter.

Comment: One directory, one project.

Comment: I have One Course > Many presentations and Notes. Challenging to have only one directory.

Comment: Course *The world of microstuff* A) *molecules* B) *bacteria* C) LegoBricks. Seems far too easy for me.

Comment: @Johannes_B Put Diagnostics there and you get much more than easy.

Answer (score 3):

The LaTeX build wrapper [ltx2any](https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any) may be a solution. One of its main features is

> Keeps your main directory clean by default.

---

The basic usage is

```
ltx2any filename.tex
```

and all the auxiliary files will be in a subdirectory. For more options read the linked webpage or run `ltx2any --help`.

Comment: Can you add an example how the workflow works with, please.

Comment: I am not sure how this app differs from `latexmk -c`.

Comment: What is the default way to install the app and test it? It seems: 1 install *listen* (ruby); 2 ltx2any is ruby command so put in path. It would be nice to install it through some manager application.

Comment: @Masi This is totally different to `latexmk -c`, as `latexmk -c` just deletes the files. In `ltx2any` all the files are still present.

Comment: @Masi Yes, it needs ruby. If you do not want to add it to your path, just call call the executable file with its whole path. If you have further questions about the installation, ask the author on `github`, I made the experience, that he is very responsive and helpful.

Comment: I opened a ticket about it here https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any/issues/80

Comment: (+1) The use of multiple cores to run TikZ externalisations in parallel is the most attractive feature for me - I waited 45 minutes the other day for a file to compile and still ended up going to class with the handout version of my slides i.e. without incremental overlay specifications. Pah.

Comment: @Masi I think the README already contains the information needed to install. Setting PATH etc. is a basic thing on any Unix-ish system but it differs from OS to OS and, sometimes, from release to release. So how to set it on one version of OS X is not the same as how to set it on another (in some cases) and similarly for GNU/Linux. Note that you may be able to get it through a package manager. (On a Linux/BSD/etc. system, this is your distro's package manager. On OS X, it would be your choice from the additions available although this is never as satisfactory as the GNU/Linux etc. setups.)

Answer (score 2):

If your editor is texstudio, you find a solution here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Tips%20and%20Tricks/#using-a-separate-directory-for-auxiliary-files

But you can create only one directory for all process-files.

Comment: The solution should not be editor specific. One directory for all process-files is ok.