# Local central figures repository

Tags: graphics, repositories

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically Locate Included Figures and Graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12986/automatically-locate-included-figures-and-graphics)

This question is related to the workflow with LaTeX, more then it actually related to LateX... However, I would be happy to know what is the best practice, and I guess this can be of interest to the community.

**Goal:** Different project (in the general sense) have different .tex files and will most likely live in different locations on the system. Nevertheless, the projects may share one or more components, e.g. figures. It is very likely that `fig.png` will be used in both `~/project1/project1.tex` and in `~/project2/project2.tex`. I want to have a central location where I will store *all* my images and the different TeX files will use the same location.

**Possible Solution:** Use symbolic links. Create a directory `~/figures_repository` and add symbolic link in `~/project1` and `~/project2` to the figures directory. This works nicely. But it introduces problems.

**The problem:** I can think of two problems with this approach:

1. When trying to share `project1` with someone using something like `zip`, then all the files in the repository will be added to the zip file. This is most likely bad.
2. Version controlling systems (SVN, GIT etc.): How do they handle this? Will they also control *all* the figures in the repository?

**Possible Alternatives:**

1. Somehow do it the other way around. That is, in each project's directory have a figures folder `~/project1/figures`, and link all the figures from this directory to the repository.
2. Mac users may be able to use the `smart folders`. Somehow create a smart folder which finds all the figures in all projects.

**The Question:** What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do either of [these](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14219/215) [questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14762/215) help?

Answer (score 3):

I think that [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12986/automatically-locate-included-figures-and-graphics/12987#12987) will help you as it describes all available options